# Point Newly Created Python File To Venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

I have a process that spins up a python file. I need this new python file to run on a venv that I know the filepath for. Does anyone know how to force the new python file to run on my venv instead of the default python installation.

For example, after the python file gets created, I could just navigate to it in my file explorer and double click the file to run it on my venv.

I need to be able to do this without editing the system environment variables.

No idea if this is even possible...

Comment: not sure if this is exactly what you need, but a similar thing we ran into: We want a script to run the python file in a specific venv, so instead of having the script call `python my_file.py`, it will instead call `C:\my\path\to\venv\scripts\python.exe my_file.py`. So in this case, my_file.py isn't linked to the venv in any way, but we call it from the venv